# css print header and footer on every page

Tags: css

Untitled Documenthtml,body{margin:0;padding:0}table{height:100%;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse}table td{vertical-align:top}.footer{position:fixed;height:100px;background:red;bottom:0;width:100%}tbody td{padding-bottom:100px}Header Lorem Ipsumis simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

content 1

content 2

content 3

content 4

content 5

content 6

content 7

content 8

content 9

content 10

content 11

content 12

content 13

content 14

content 15

content 16

content 17

content 18

content 19

content 20

content 21

content 22

content 23

content 24

content 25

content 26

content 27

content 28

content 29

content 30

content 31

content 32

content 33

content 34

content 35

content 36

content 37

content 38

content 39

content 40

content 41

content 42

content 43

content 44

content 45

content 46

content 47

content 48

content 49

content 50

content - last

Footer Lorem Ipsumis simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: overlap  problem

Comment: Please can you fix the formatting of your HTML code. I tried but then came out all on a single line which is just as unhelpful. Please also add some explanation to the question itself as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply `position: fixed;` rule to header and footer elements.

Comment: position: fixed;  try but overlap problem

Comment: @AkashDesigner can you provide codepen with your code?